# Textboxes are not updated when the ViewModel's data changes

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have implemented my first WPF MVVM Window.  On loading the window a method is called that fetches data from an Access database, and all appropriate textboxes are bound to the EmployeeModel's properties.

I also have a button called Refresh that runs the same method to fetch the Employee data from the database, for testing purposes I have made the Refresh button fetch a different employee ID.

However none of the window's fields update with the new EmployeeModel.  I've used breakpoints to find there is no issue saving the new data to the EmployeeModel, but no textbox appear to be updated with this new data.

Following guides online, I have used INotifyProperyChanged and use UpdateSourceTrigger in my view.

**EmployeeModel**

```
class EmployeeModel : MyDbConnector, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _employeeId;
    private string _firstname;

    public int EmployeeId
    {
        get => _employeeId;
        set
        {
            if (_employeeId != value)
            {
                _employeeId = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public string Firstname
    {
        get => _firstname;
        set
        {
            if (_firstname != value)
            {
                _firstname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }

    public static EmployeeModel FindById(int id)
    {
        //code omitted
    }
```

**EmployeeViewModel**

```
class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }

    public EmployeeViewModel()
    {
        LoadEmployee(100);
    }

    public bool LoadEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        if (!DbConnector.OpenDB())
            return false;

        Employee = EmployeeModel.FindById(employeeId);

        DbConnector.CloseDB();

        if (Employee == null)
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public void Refresh()
    {
        // Load a different employee
        if (!LoadEmployee(102))
            MessageBox.Show("An error has occurred");
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<Label Width="100" Content="Employee ID"/>
<TextBox Width="100" IsEnabled="False" Text="{Binding Employee.EmployeeId, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<Label Width="100" Content="First name"/>
<TextBox Text="{Binding Employee.Firstname, TargetNullValue='', UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Comment: A good rule of thumb is, don't call it a ViewModel unless it implements INotifyPropertyChanged fully.

Comment: I have been implementing my Models with INotifyPropertyChanged.  Have I got it the wrong way round and it should be implemented on ViewModels instead.  Is INotifyPropertyChanged not neccesary on Models at all?

Comment: Pretty much yeah. Models are usually POCO classes for sending stuff back and forth to the data layer. But if your “model” classes act like viewmodels — properties bound in the XAML etc. — then they need INPC.

Comment: In mvvm models should not implement INotifyPropertyChanged since models are just the data entities (they don't belong to the UI layer). If you want to work with your "models" the way you did it the you should create a wrapper around the model, that wrapper would be basically the same class but with the INotifyPropertyChanged implementation and all of the properties in the wrapper should point to the properties in the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're changing the entire Model for a new Model object but you're not notifying the UI that you did it. Your EmployeeViewModel class should implement INotifyPropertyChanged just like you did with the employee model and then the property Employee should call OnPropertyChanged method

```cs
    private EmployeeModel _employee;
    public EmployeeModel Employee {
        get { return _employee; }
        set {
            if(_employee!=value) {
                _employee=value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
         }
    }
```